# where para deletar registros que foram inseridos há um determinado tempo

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, oracle

Queia ajuda para criar um `delete` com `where` caso o registro tenha sido inserido a mais de 5 minutos.

Tenho a tabela de marcação de ponto com as colunas:

- cd_cadastro - inteiro
- cd_empresa - inteiro
- cd_matricula - inteiro
- dt_ponto - varchar (porque estou enviando da aplicação `Java` como `String` a data)

A ideia é:

`delete from ponto where "registro foi inserido há mais de cinco minutos"`

ou

`delete from ponto where hora_atual - dt_ponto > cincoMinutos`

Ou se há outra alternativa para esta solução.

Preciso disso pois é uma regra da empresa que uma pessoa só possa inserir registro de ponto a cada 5 minutos. Então, essa é uma tabela que serve como referência do tempo de marcação de ponto. Na aplicação java, eu faço uma verificação, se houver registro de matricula nessa tabela é porque o usuário registrou ponto a menos de cinco minutos e não pode inserir outro registro.

Comment: Informa um exemplo do que você quer fazer, é facil solucionar isso, mas envia os dados de exemplo

Comment: Não deveria verificar por duplicatas, e caso houver mais de um registro em menos de 5 minutos, fazer a remoção?

Comment: não, porque é preciso evitar que haja mais de uma inserção pela mesma pessoa em menos de cinco minutos.

Comment: Converta sua string para um campo datetime e utilize a função `DATE_SUB` com `INTERVAL 5 MINUTES`.

Comment: @GuilhermeBrügger, muito obrigado pela dica, de verdade. E obrigado a todos por colaborarem na solução!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a função [DATE_SUB()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub) para calcular a diferença de 5 minutos data, assim:

```
WHERE dt_ponto <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE);
```

O `INTERVAL` pode ser HOUR, MINUTE, etc, e como é DATE_SUB, vai subtrair 5 minutos, se fosse DATE_ADD, somaria.

Veja aqui um exemplo funcionando: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mrJ1axymtQmoHLhKJb2bXc/0

Comment: no caso dele, ele tem o `dt_ponto` como `varchar` funcionaria também?

Comment: sim, só converter para datetime